# How do I make my JQuery .on('click', ) work more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, animation, click

I'm trying to create a sliding pop-up, where you can click on a label to slide and reveal the content, and then click again on the same label to hide the content. I'm using JQuery to animate the div class, but the animation only gets triggered by the click once. I tested, and both of the functions do work, but once it's triggered the one way, it wont trigger again. Here's the JavaScript, the functions are nested in an if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listSlide = $(".tutor-list").css("top");
    (listSlide === "0px")? $(document).on('click', '#list-slide', function(){
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "200px"});
        }) : $(document).on('click', '#list-slide', function(){
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "0px"});
        }); 
});
```

I'm very new to Javascript, so it is possible that the issue lies in a syntax error or some fundamental flaw, but I can't find what's wrong with it.

Comment: Currently you're attaching the click listener conditionally. But this code is executed only once (on DOM ready), you'll never get another listener attached. You've to attach a single listener, and check and update `listSlide` inside that listener, and animate to the direction based on that check.

Comment: You should check current position inside onclick event and animate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you are checking the **initial** state of the top property. Then you are binding the click depending on the **initial** top property.

You want to use the **current** top property. This property changes when the user clicks the `#last-slide`. Therefore you need to check the state in the click callback and then handle depending on this value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#list-slide', function(){
        var top = parseFloat($(".tutor-list").css("top"));

        if(top == 0){
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "200px"});
        }
        else{
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "0px"});
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  position: relative;
}

.tutor-list{
  background: #ccccff;
  border: 1px dashed #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="list-slide">Toggle list</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="tutor-list">This is the list</div>
      </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Note that the `parseFloat()` is not really needed. <s>I just don't know whether the returned value of `jQuery.css("top")` is a string or a number.</s> In the [j-Query docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/) I could not find the return type of the `jQuery.css()` function. It sais it uses the "computed style" depending on the browser. About the computed style the docs say:

> [C]omputed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

So I assume that there may be different return values for `top` property too. Therefore to go fully cross-browser I always use the `parseFloat()` function. In addition the unit is not important here. It doesn't matter if it is 0px, 0em or just 0. (Note that for other cases it *does* matter. 1px is not equal to 1em. For this case use the [`jQuery.offser().top`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) which always returns px.)

---

I don't know your exact setup but you may also want to check out [`jQuery.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options). This function hides your list. The `jQuery.hide()` can take arguments for animations so you end up with the same result. Personally I prefere the `jQuery.hide()` function because it changes the css `display` property. This way the element doesn't end up somewhere in the space but it is defined as not visible. I think this is the better solution.

---

Also you can change your click binding function to the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#last-slide').on('click', function(){
        // ...
    });
});
```

Personally I prefere this way because it looks nicer to me. Note that the first method (used by you) binds the event to the document and then filters, this means that reloading the content by js/ajax will *keep* the functionality. This may be intended but also may not be intended (maybe you are initializing the page again).

Comment: Thanks! I found an interesting quirk. the click would work multiple times, but once the "top" value reached 200px, it would stop working. I rearranged the logic of the if statement for it to work consistantly, and now my code looks like this: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tutor-list-button").on('click', function() {

        var listSlide = $(".tutor-list").css("top");

        if (listSlide === "200px") {
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "60px"});
        } else {
            $(".tutor-list").animate({ top: "200px"});
        }

    });

});` ps no parseFloat

Comment: I don't know why it stops working. This should not happen. I added a working example of my initial code. It is working multiple times without any problems. Maybe your setup is special. Also while writing my example I recognized that you are maybe looking for [`jQuery.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-options) which seems (of my point of view) to fit better to what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding click event only once and only when the document is ready. Therefore one of the `if/else` sections are not binding. You can move `if/else` blocks into the `click` binding as followings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#list-slide', function() {

        var listSlide = $(".tutor-list").css("top");

        if (listSlide === "0px") {
            $(".tutor-list").animate({top: "200px"});
        } else {
            $(".tutor-list").animate({ top: "0px"});
        }

    });

});
```